# How to use clipboard.js with Ajax? (data-clipboard)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clipboard.js

I have Clipboard.js working fine on my test site, I can copy using data-clipboard as such.

```
<a href="#">
<i class="icon-link icon-1x fa-fw" id="d_clip_button_x" data-clipboard-text="copythistext" title="Copy direct link"></i></a>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="copy/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"> var client = new Clipboard(  document.getElementById('d_clip_button_x') );</script>
```

But when I have content from an Ajax call the same code no longer functions. I have read some ways and tutorials on how to get Ajax to work well with Clipboard.js but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. As I understand it I need to retrigger the function, but how can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to get a value of `d_clip_button_x` element?

Comment: Yes and that's currently working fine. When I click on the font-awesome icon I get the value of  But when `d_clip_button_x `, but the same code doesn't work on a Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

i tried on my end. clipboard.js uses extensive triggers to get the `data` attribute and binds when the page finishes loading.
so, in case the data is fetched from ajax, clipboard, won't binds them as u wish to. 
for the solution, here is the trick.
first of all, make one generic copy button which works, give it a ID, suppose we give is `d_clip_button_villa_XXX`.

```
<a style="display:none" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="icon-link icon-1x fa-fw" id="d_clip_button_villa_XXX" data-clipboard-text="" title="Copy direct link"> </i> </a> <script type="text/javascript"> var client = new Clipboard( document.getElementById('d_clip_button_villa_XXX') ); </script>
```

now, instead of making same buttons, use any element like `<a>` tag and mention 2 events->

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="copytxt('here is the text')" onclick="clkd(); return false;">copy</a>
```

now make two functions->

```
function copytxt(txt){ 
jQuery('#d_clip_button_villa_XXX').attr('data-clipboard-text', txt); 
} 

function clkd(){ 
jQuery('#d_clip_button_villa_XXX').click(); 
}
```

this will work with ajax also